# how to use sshpass to chain commands?

Tags: ssh, sshpass

I want to use `sshpass` to run some commands

I have the following command:

`sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@hostname "sudo su - someOtherUser; mkdir -p ${HOME}/apps/testApp/; cd ${HOME}/apps/testApp/; git clone <gitRepo>"`

However, the operation hangs.
I assume it's `sudo su - kdb` command used to change users when connecting to my server